# VSTS Build Nuget Package Assembly not in lib

Tags: nuget-package, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to build a C# Library project into a Nuget package using Visual Studio Team Services Build, the project is stored in Github and I have committed a nuspec file to the repository.

However when I run the build is successful however the Nuget package is empty because the Assemblies in the build are not in the lib folder. How can I add a lib folder and copy the Assemblies to it during the visual studio team services build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a build task Copy Files to copy the files from the output to the lib directory. The Copy Files task can be found under the Utility tab when adding build steps.